# PHP DateTime setTimezone 2038

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, year2038

I convert all dates with DateTime (from UTC to Europe/Vienna) in my project. Now I have dates with above 2038, and cannot get the correct time.

Example Code:

```
$met = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Vienna');
$utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');

$date = new DateTime('2043-08-04 08:00:00', $utc);
$date->setTimezone($met);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Output is: 2043-08-04 09:00:00 instead of 2043-08-04 10:00:00
```

Between 2043-03-29 and 2043-10-25 there is to calculate +2 hours from UTC, because of "summertime".

If I change 2043-08-04 08:00:00 to 2037-08-04 08:00:00 I get the correct time.

I know it is a 2038 problem with integer 32 bit, but how I can use integer 64 bit with DateTime setTimezone function?

Thanks

Comment: The `DateTime` class is not affected by 2038 issue, even on 32-bit PHP.

Comment: ... except when it is (see answers so far). Oh my... :)

Comment: Since time zone and daylight savings laws change, they can't be relied upon to be the same that far into the future anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If the issue had anything to do with overflowing 32-bit Unix timestamps you'd be getting dates around 1970 and similar totally incorrect results. However, your result is only off by one hour. In fact, we could argue that the *hour* is correct since you're only getting a wrong *time zone offset*, as you can see if you print time zone information:

```
var_dump($date);
echo $date->format('c');
```

```
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2043-08-04 09:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Vienna"
}
2043-08-04T09:00:00+01:00
```

This suggests that the internal time database is missing information for year 2043 as it has for current year. We can further confirm this with:

```
$met = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Vienna');
var_dump($met->getTransitions((new DateTime('2017-01-01'))->format('U'), (new DateTime('2017-12-31'))->format('U')));
var_dump($met->getTransitions((new DateTime('2043-01-01'))->format('U'), (new DateTime('2043-12-31'))->format('U')));
```

This code (that apparently needs to run on a 32-bit platforms) prints:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(1483225200)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "2016-12-31T23:00:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(3600)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "CET"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(1490490000)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "2017-03-26T01:00:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(7200)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(4) "CEST"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(1509238800)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "2017-10-29T01:00:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(3600)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "CET"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(2303679600)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "2042-12-31T23:00:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(3600)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "CET"
  }
}
```

As PHP is aware of it, year 2043 is CET from January to December.

This information comes from the [Olson database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database):

> a collaborative compilation of information about the world's time zones, primarily intended for use with computer programs and operating systems

The PHP manual includes [instructions to update it](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.installation.php), in case it already has the missing data. If it doesn't, you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Aparrently the `DateTimeZone` transitions are limited to 2037. That's why you are getting the right results until that year:

```
$met = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Vienna');

print_r($met->getTransitions());
```

The last entries are:

```
[139] => Array
    (
        [ts] => 2108595600
        [time] => 2036-10-26T01:00:00+0000
        [offset] => 3600
        [isdst] => 
        [abbr] => CET
    )

[140] => Array
    (
        [ts] => 2121901200
        [time] => 2037-03-29T01:00:00+0000
        [offset] => 7200
        [isdst] => 1
        [abbr] => CEST
    )

[141] => Array
    (
        [ts] => 2140045200
        [time] => 2037-10-25T01:00:00+0000
        [offset] => 3600
        [isdst] => 
        [abbr] => CET
    )
```